# Hide a gridView row`s item in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Im trying to hide a couple of row`s items in the gridview with specified parameters. If the label "ProductDetail" in that row has any value from the array, it should hide the button which is "btnDuplicateRow"

```
protected void grdEstimateDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{           
    String[] arr = new String[6];
    arr[0] = "Malarkey";                

    for (int i = 0; i < grdEstimateDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Label lblctrl = (Label)grdEstimateDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("ProductDetail");

        var btnDuplicateRow1 = (ImageButton)grdEstimateDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("btnDuplicateRow");

        if (arr.Contains(lblctrl.Text))
        {
             btnDuplicateRow1.Visible = false;
        }               
    }
}

<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblProductDetail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductDetail") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>

<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnDuplicateRow" ImageUrl="~/Web/Images/add-18x18.png" 
    CommandName="DuplicateRow" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" 
    ToolTip="Duplicate"/>
```

Now I'm getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error.

Another thing that I tried is to hide the row

```
e.Row.Visible = false;
```

But still does not work.

thanks.

**EDITED:**
Gridview:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product/Detail" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductDetail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductDetail") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='Friday'></asp:Label>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField Visible="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>


                            <td>
                                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnDuplicateRow" ImageUrl="~/Web/Images/add-18x18.png" 
                                    CommandName="DuplicateRow" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" 
                                    ToolTip="Duplicate"/>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Khaki"></SelectedRowStyle>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work. May need to tweak in order to locate the button control

```
   protected void grdEstimateDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {   
        String[] arr = new String[6];
        arr[0] = "Malarkey";
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          {
           // Following line may not be necessary but could prove to be usefull 
           //System.Data.DataRowView dr = (System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
           e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";
           Label lblctrl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblProductDetail");
           ImageButton btnDuplicateRow1 = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnDuplicateRow");
            if (arr.Contains(lblctrl.Text))
            {
               btnDuplicateRow1.Visible = false;
            }
       }
    }
```

......

Comment: Im getting this error: error CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry,  @Fresher, My Bad. I corrected to "e.Row"  That should work fine.
 I cobbled code from several sources so overlooked that.

Comment: I tried this before, but im still getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 error..

Comment: which control is giving that error? is it both
It looks like you using a templated Column ? can you post your entire Grid or at least the columns that contain the controls?

Comment: I found one error that could be the fix  You where trying to locate the label control "lblProductDetail"  using the datafield "ProductDetail" I modified my code so that it is looking for the label. You can also evaluate the value directly from the datafield. Let me know if you are still getting an error.

Comment: I added gridview.

Comment: Please read my comment just before your edit. I think the issue was in how you were looking for the label. I edited my answer to reflect that. Please try it and let e know.

Comment: It all works, @DaniDev! I feel stupid i didnt see that mistake. The day was too long. Btw, do you know how its possible to hide the Select button in the first column? It allows to open more details and I cant see it on markup. http://prntscr.com/hyaond

Comment: Glad I was able to help ;-)  . I added a line that should hide your select button (if it is in the first cell).   Would greatly appreciate accepting my answer. Cheers!

Comment: @DeniDev, in this way the first cell is removed and all other cells move to the right, messing up the row..